# Expense Tracker for keeping track of payment information

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, tkinter, sqlite

This system is an expense tracker. It allows ordinary people to track expenses, like bills, car notes, and keep up with the payments they make. I had this idea after my father and mother began to mess around with a notebook full of bill transactions and I thought I could make a program to handle this data for them. 16-Year-old aspired CS major. I just want to see if there are any major improvements I could make with what I have so far. I plan on building it up even further to improve user experience.

```
'''
Created By Ronald Colyar 2/13/2018
'''
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

conn1 = sqlite3.connect('Expense Data.db')
c1 = conn1.cursor()

class MainPageGui:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title(string = 'Expense Tracker')
        master.iconbitmap('Expense.ico')
        master.resizable(width = False , height = False)
        #configuration of window
        master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        #placement
        w = 505
        h = 217
        ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
        master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
        #creation of widgets
        self.Header = tk.Label(root , text = 'Your Expenses:', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.headernames = tk.Label(master, text ='Company , Amount Due , Account Number , Amount Paid , Due Date , ID Number , First , Last' , fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , columnspan = 5, sticky = 'we')
        self.credit = tk.Label(master, text = 'Created By : Ronald Colyar', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 3 ,column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master , bd = 0 )
        self.listbox.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 ,columnspan = 5,  sticky = 'we')


        self.Add_expense = ttk.Button(master, text = '+', command = Add_expense_win).grid(row = 0 , column = 2 , sticky = 'we')
        self.remove_expense = ttk.Button(master, text = '-'  ,command = remove_window).grid(row = 0 , column = 3, sticky = 'we')
        self.Advanced_expense = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Advanced Statistics', command = advanced_win).grid(row = 0 , column = 4, sticky = 'we')
        self.update = ttk.Button(master , text = 'Update' , command = update_expenses).grid(row = 0 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        
class Add_expense:
    def __init__(self , master):
        self.master = master
        master.title(string = 'Add Expense')
        master.iconbitmap('Expense.ico')
        master.resizable(width = False , height = True)
    

        #creation of labels
        self.first_name_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'First name', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.last_name_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'Last name', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 1 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.Company_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'Company', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.amount_due_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'amount due', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 3 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.account_number_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'account number', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 7 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.amount_paid_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'amount paid', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 9 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
        self.due_date_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'due date', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 9 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.IDnum_label =tk.Label(master, text = 'ID number(Special Feature)**REQUIRED', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 7 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we')
        self.ErrorMessage = tk.Message(master , text = None , fg = 'Red' , font = 'times 12 bold')
        self.ErrorMessage.grid(row  =12 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we' ,columnspan = 2 )
        self.credit = tk.Label(master, text= 'Creator: Ronald Colyar Jr.', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 13 , column =0 , sticky = 'we')
        #creation of entrys
        self.first_name_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.first_name_entry.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.last_name_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.last_name_entry.grid(row = 2 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.Company_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.Company_entry.grid(row = 4 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.amount_due_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.amount_due_entry.grid(row = 4 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.account_number_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.account_number_entry.grid(row = 8 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.amount_paid_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.amount_paid_entry.grid(row = 10 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.due_date_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.due_date_entry.grid(row = 10 , column = 1 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)
        self.IDnum_name_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
        self.IDnum_name_entry.grid(row = 8, column = 1 , sticky = 'we', pady = 5 , padx = 5)

        #menu
        self.Save_menu = tk.Menu(master)
        self.Save_menu.add_command(label = 'Save Expense' , command= Save_Info)
        master.config(menu = self.Save_menu)
    def ChangeText(self,Text):
        self.ErrorMessage.config(text = Text)

def total_debt():
    #the paid amount stored in database
    total_paid  = c1.execute("SELECT amount_paid  FROM Expenses")
    #placeholders
    combined_paid = 0
    combined_debt = 0

    for row in total_paid:
        combined_paid += int(row[0])

    #the debt stored in database
    total_owed = c1.execute("SELECT Amount_Due  FROM Expenses") 

    #combining all data from amount due 
    for num in total_owed:
        combined_debt += int(num[0])

    #getting the sum of whats left over to pay 
    results = combined_debt - combined_paid

    #checking to see if we get an negative int witch means no debt
    if results < 0:
        return 0
    #if not negative , return the amount
    else:
        return "{:,}".format(results)

def paid_combiner():
    placeholder = 0
    #searching for the price of the user
    total = c1.execute("SELECT amount_paid  FROM Expenses")
    for row in total:
        
        placeholder += int(row[0])
        
    return "{:,}".format(placeholder)

def category_searcher(category):
    global notfounderror 
    numb_of_row = 0 
    #searching the database for the information provided by user
    c1.execute("SELECT * FROM Expenses WHERE " +str(category) + "= ?" ,  (str(searchentry.get()),))

    #if the results are not there
    if c1.fetchall() == []:
        #updating user error message
        notfounderror.config(text = 'Please Search Again , No ' + str(searchvar.get()) + " '"+ str(searchentry.get())+ "'")
    else:
        #removing previous contents
        resultsbox.delete(0 , 'end')
        #insertion of data
        for row in  c1.execute("SELECT * FROM Expenses WHERE " +str(category) + "= ?" ,  (str(searchentry.get()),)):
            numb_of_row +=1
            resultsbox.insert('end' , str(numb_of_row)+ ':' + str(row))

def advanced_Statistics_algo():
    #checks
    if searchvar.get() == 'account number':
        category_searcher('account_number')
    elif searchvar.get() == 'Due date' :
        category_searcher('due_date')
    elif searchvar.get() == 'first name':
        category_searcher('first_name_on_account')
    elif searchvar.get() ==  'last name':
        category_searcher('second_name_on_account')
    else: 
        category_searcher('Company')

def advanced_win():
    global searchvar , searchentry, notfounderror , resultsbox
    advanced_window = tk.Toplevel()
    advanced_window.title(string = 'Advanced Information')
    advanced_window.iconbitmap('Expense.ico')
    advanced_window.resizable(width =   True, height = False)

    #placement
    w = 820
    h = 270
    ws = advanced_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = advanced_window.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
    advanced_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))



    #creation of widgets
    headernames = tk.Label(advanced_window, text ='Company , Amount Due , Account Number , Amount Paid , Due Date , ID Number , First , Last' , fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    total_paid_label = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = 'Total paid :' + str(paid_combiner())+ '$', font = 'times 15', fg = 'dark green' ).grid(row = 7 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
    total_debt_label = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = 'Total Amount left to pay: ' +  str(total_debt())+ '$', font = 'times 15 ', fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 6 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')

    searchvar = tk.StringVar()
    options = ['Options' ,'account number' , 'Due date' , 'first name' , 'last name' , 'company' ]
    searchtype = ttk.OptionMenu(advanced_window , searchvar, *options ).grid(row = 0, column = 1 , sticky = 'we')

    searchentry = ttk.Entry(advanced_window)
    searchentry.grid(row = 0 , column = 2 , sticky = 'we')

    searchbutton =  ttk.Button(advanced_window , text = 'Search' , command=  advanced_Statistics_algo).grid(row = 0 , column = 3 , sticky = 'we')

    resultsbox = tk.Listbox(advanced_window, bd = 0)
    resultsbox.grid(row  = 4  , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')

    notfounderror = tk.Label(advanced_window , text = None , fg = 'Red')
    notfounderror.grid(row =8 , column = 0, sticky = 'we')

def expense_inserter():
    #all contents of the database
    info = c1.execute("SELECT * FROM Expenses")
    number_of_row = 0

    for row in info:
        number_of_row+=1
        #inserting all rows 
        mainPage.listbox.insert('end' , str(number_of_row)+ ':' + str(row))

def update_expenses():
    global mainPage
    mainPage.listbox.delete(0 , 'end')
    expense_inserter()
def remove_algo():
    info  = c1.execute("""SELECT * FROM Expenses WHERE IDnum= ?""" ,  (mainentry.get(),))
    #checking to see if the Expense is in the database

    if mainentry.get() == 'ALL':
        c1.execute("""DELETE FROM Expenses""")
        conn1.commit()
        error_msg.config(text = 'Everything Deleted')
    
    elif info.fetchall() == []:
        #updating the user on the status of the request if there is no Expense there
        error_msg.config(text = 'No Expense Under That ID number')
    else: 
        #updating the user on the status of the request if there is an Expense there
        
        c1.execute("""DELETE  FROM Expenses WHERE IDnum= ? """ , (mainentry.get(),))
        conn1.commit()
        error_msg.config(text = 'Expense Deleted')

def remove_window():
    global mainentry , error_msg
    Remove_win = tk.Toplevel()
    Remove_win.title(string = 'Remove Expense')
    Remove_win.iconbitmap('Expense.ico')
    Remove_win.resizable(width = False , height = False)

    #placement
    w = 340
    h = 200
    ws = Remove_win.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = Remove_win.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
    Remove_win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))
    #creation of widgets
    mainmessage = tk.Message(Remove_win , text = 'Welcome to the remove expense section where you can remove expenses. Keep in mind once you remove an expense you cannot recover , enter in the ID number of the expense to remove it, To delete all expenses enter "ALL"' , fg = 'dark green').grid(row = 0 , sticky = 'we ' , column = 0)

    mainentry = ttk.Entry(Remove_win)
    mainentry.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')

    submitbutton = ttk.Button(Remove_win , text = 'CONFIRM', command = remove_algo)
    submitbutton.grid(row = 1 , column = 1,  sticky = 'we')

    error_msg = tk.Label(Remove_win , text = None , fg= 'red' , font = 'times 12 bold')
    error_msg.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')

def intcheck(Data):
    try:
        int(Data)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def Add_expense_win():
    global addpage 
    add_window = tk.Toplevel()
    #placement
    w = 350
    h = 350
    ws = add_window.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = add_window.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y =  (hs/2) - (h/2)
    add_window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x , y))

    addpage = Add_expense(add_window)
    add_window.mainloop()

def Save_Info():
    global addpage
    #grabbing all data from user
    firstname_data = addpage.first_name_entry.get()
    last_name_data = addpage.last_name_entry.get()
    company_data = addpage.Company_entry.get()
    amount_due_data = addpage.amount_due_entry.get()
    account_number_data = addpage.account_number_entry.get()
    amount_paid_data = addpage.amount_paid_entry.get()
    due_date_data = addpage.due_date_entry.get()
    IDnumber_data = addpage.IDnum_name_entry.get()

    #checking to see if the following are integers
    if intcheck(amount_paid_data) == False or intcheck(amount_due_data) == False or len(IDnumber_data) < 3 :
        addpage.ChangeText('ERROR:Please Make Sure The following do not contain integers(numbers) : Amount paid , Amount Due , Also Make sure ID number is filled out ')
    #storing data into database
    else:
        c1.execute("INSERT INTO Expenses VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
            ((company_data) , (amount_due_data) , (account_number_data) , (amount_paid_data) , (due_date_data) , (IDnumber_data) , (firstname_data) , (last_name_data))
            )
        conn1.commit()
        addpage.ChangeText('Expense Added')

def main():
    global root , mainPage
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainPage = MainPageGui(root)
    expense_inserter()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
conn1.close()
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: The code doesn't currently run. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I messed up on transferring the code onto code review , try it now

Comment: I can't run your code right now as I'm on my phone, but it looks fine to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You import `tkinter` 3 different ways. I personally recommend using `from module import a, b, c`, but you should at least stay consistent.
2. You should separate your graphics and database code.
3. Avoid global variables. You can but stuff inside a class instead.